# Keychain warning in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

here is my code:

```
    //Set
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Animex" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:username forKey:kSecValueData];
[keychain setObject:password forKey:kSecAttrAccount];

[keychain release];
```

It works perfectly, but I get a warning:

```
"passing argument 2 of 'set object:forkey' discards qualifiers from pointer target type.
```

What does it mean?
How to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the parameter to id.

```
[keychain setObject:username forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
[keychain setObject:password forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

kSecValueData and kSecAttrAccount are CFTypeRef and setObject:forKey: expects an id.

CFTypeRef is defined as:

```
typedef const void * CFTypeRef;
```

It's the fact that it's a const that's giving you this warning.